# How to output data to table depending on what option was selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown

Basically I want to create a table of two rows and 4 columns. In the first column I want to be able to select something with a drop down. Once selected the data associated with that selection will be outputted to the other 3 columns in the table. I am new to this so please understand.

I have shown with x,y,z where I want my data values to be displayed. So for example, if I select rose, then the temperature, humidity, and moisture will be shown where x,y,z is respectively.

[code i am working with](https://jsfiddle.net/v0wt2kjd/1/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      table {
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
      }

      td,
      th {
        border: 1px solid #dddddd;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px;
      }

      tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #dddddd;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Select Plant</th>
        <th>Temp</th>
        <th>Humidity</th>
        <th>Moisture</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="daisy">daisy
    <option value="tulip">tulip
    <option value="rose">rose
    <option value="sunflower">sunflower

</select>


          <p id="demo"></p>


          <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
            }

          </script>

          <td>x</td>
          <td>y</td>
          <td>z</td>

      </tr>


    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a little bit of information about what the table should look like? How is your data structured? In general, you'll want create your HTML structure of a `<table>`, where the first cell in each row contains a `<select>`. You can then use JavaScript's `addEventListener` to listen for `change` event. Next, you'll want to update the html contents of the other columns. I think you can find out how to do many of these using answers that are already available on this site, so I hope breaking down the problem down gives you a place to start.

Comment: The table would be 2 by 4. The first row would be header. The second row column 1 cell would have a drop down where I can select a car model. Once I select a car model, the data for that specific car would be displayed in row 2 column 2,3,4 for cost, MPG, and top speed, respectively.

Comment: " if I select rose, then the temperature, humidity, and moisture will be shown where x,y,z is respectively."  Would you tell me where the temperature, humidity, and moisture of data come from?

Comment: They would be coming from a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For creating a table using javascript you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_table.asp).

For creating a select box using javascript you can refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/j).

I think you need to capture the onchange event of select box, you can refer
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp).